# Expected development of 'fitness histogram' for PSO over time

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I'm plotting the fitness histogram of my particle swarm optimizer - i.e. the individual fitness scores for each particle and iteration - during a run.

The problem tackled is basically curve fitting/predicting time series data.

In some runs I'm seeing a rugged landscape with no tendency towards a stabilization of fitness scores across the swarm like here:
[image: PSO Histogram]

Is my interpretation correct that these are basically **failed runs**?

That is the way I'm reading the results of these runs is that the best solutions yet (or in PSO terminology *positions*) of the best particles don't necessarily point towards an optimal solution (with positions nearby also possessing better than average fitness scores) but are merely lucky draws.

(Sorry if I'm confusing terminology - PSO is a new area for me and my background is in ML and Genetic Algorithms in particular)